# Can I disable sending a new case alert when duplicating a case?

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow

I have a Screen Flow that duplicates a case. It works fine.

However, I want to disable the alert for the owner as well as the case contact, for this specific action. So, if a new case is created, the alerts should be sent. But when a case is duplicated - I want to disable these emails.

I use flow. Is it possible ?

This is my Flow:
[image]

It's a screen flow.

- I get the case to clone
- I create the new cloned case
- I reset some of the fields (status, subject, Closed, closed date etc)
- I create the new cloned case
- *the redirect to the new cloned case record.

- I don't have a 'Case Creation Tempalte'
  [image]

I use email-to-case

Comment: Could you please elaborate in terms of how you set up the alerts to the case owner & contact?

Comment: Depending on what your flow does (and assuming you have control over what goes on in the flow), you may be able to get around it by putting a flag on Case called something like "Is Duplicate", set the flag to true during the duplication process, and modify your alert functionality accordingly so it doesn't send the alert if that flag is true.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe how you sending the alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**+1** for *Victor Lockwood*'s comment. Yes, you will need to provide the difference between your regular `case` and *duplicate `case`* which is created based on your flow.

- So you need to create a new `checkbox`  field (maybe you can hide this from the layout) and use it in your flow to enable it during case creation, then update your email alert criteria so that `checkbox` field needs to be `false` when it's triggered. So when your flow creates a duplicate case, that email alert is skipped due to that `checkbox` field value.

OR

- If your duplicate case has a separate/different process compared to the regular case, please feel free to create a new `record type` and create your duplicate case (created by your flow) based on that record type and skip the other record type on your email alert.

Hope it will give some idea to you.

Thanks.